# Disable the request to auto-save passwords

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

While using web browser like Mozilla Firefox or Google Chrome, the browser pops up a dialog for "Would you like to remember the password on https://.....?"

Every new account type I need to click "Never remember password for this site." How can I disable this prompt from the setting panel in both Firefox and Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Google Chrome**, under Settings > +Show advanced settings, uncheck "Offer to save your web passwords".

In **Mozilla Firefox**, under Options > Security, uncheck "Remember passwords for sites".